# Adding array of object inside an object JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have set of 2 data objects and they have one same element. How do I merge theme into single array object?

```
var itemList = [];

var categoryList = [{
      cat_id: 1,
      cat_name: 'category1'
   },
   {
      cat_id: 2,
      cat_name: 'category2'
   }
];

var productList = [{
      cat_id: 1,
      prod_code: 'a1',
      prod_name: 'product1'
   },
   {
      cat_id: 1,
      prod_code: 'a2',
      prod_name: 'product2'
   },
   {
      cat_id: 2,
      prod_code: 'b1',
      prod_name: 'product3'
   },
   {
      cat_id: 2,
      prod_code: 'b2',
      prod_name: 'product4'
   }
]
```

It will look like this

```
itemList = [{
      cat_id: 1,
      cat_name: 'category1',
      products: [{
            prod_code: 'a1',
            prod_name: 'product1'
         },
         {
            prod_code: 'a2',
            prod_name: 'product2'
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      cat_id: 2,
      cat_name: 'category2',
      products: [{
            prod_code: 'b1',
            prod_name: 'product3'
         },
         {
            prod_code: 'b2',
            prod_name: 'product4'
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

I tried using `itemList.push` and I can't seem to get it to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the trick using `map` and `filter`

```js
var categoryList = [{
      cat_id: 1,
      cat_name: 'category1'
   },
   {
      cat_id: 2,
      cat_name: 'category2'
   }
];

var productList = [{
      cat_id: 1,
      prod_code: 'a1',
      prod_name: 'product1'
   },
   {
      cat_id: 1,
      prod_code: 'a2',
      prod_name: 'product2'
   },
   {
      cat_id: 2,
      prod_code: 'b1',
      prod_name: 'product3'
   },
   {
      cat_id: 2,
      prod_code: 'b2',
      prod_name: 'product4'
   }
];

var itemList = [...categoryList];
itemList.map(item => {
   item.products = productList.filter( pro => pro.cat_id === item.cat_id);
});
console.log(itemList);
```

Answer (score 0):

let merged first two objects = {...obj1, ...obj2};
Then push that item into itemList array. Maybe this can help you !!

Answer (score 0):

You can check my solution as below, here idea is to create a deep copy(so that categoryList will still remain the same) of the categoryList and then loop through both the lists and add the result into tempList.

```
var tempList = categoryList.map(a => Object.assign({}, a)); // just to do deep copy 

for( var i =0; i< tempList.length; i++) {
   var temp = [];
   for( var j =0; j< productList.length; j++){
       if(tempList[i]["cat_id"] == productList[j]["cat_id"]) {
           var obj = {};
           obj["prod_code"] = productList[j]["prod_code"];
           obj["prod_name"] = productList[j]["prod_name"];
           temp.push(obj);
       }
   }
   tempList[i]["products"] = temp;
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(tempList[0]));
console.log(JSON.stringify(tempList[1]));
```